# How "sqlplus /" works

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

I was wondering how sqlplus takes the username and password in connect statement "sqlplus /".

How can I change the configuration if i want to connect with "sqlplus /" with different user. It Might seems awkward but in my script "sqlplus /" is harcoded and we cannot change this. Just I want to connect with different user using same command.

Comment: Once SQLPLus has started, are you allowed to run your own commands? You can then just use SQL>connect "user/passw@db"

Comment: Even if `sqlplus` is hardcoded, you can create a wrapper with the same name and put it earlier in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Oracle documentation:

> /
>
> Represents a default logon using operating system authentication. In a default logon, SQL*Plus typically attempts to log you in using the username OPS$name, where name is your operating system username. Note that the prefix "OPS$" can be set to any other string of text.
>
> For example, you may wish to change the settings in your INIT.ORA parameters file to LOGONname or USERIDname. See the Oracle9i Database Administrator's Guide for information about operating system authentication.

So it uses your operating system details to construct your Oracle user name, meaning that you probably can't set an arbitrary name.

The Oracle initialisation parameter for specifying the prefix is [`OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/initparams147.htm) and its default value id `OPS$`.

One thing you *could* do, if you cannot change the script which calls sqlplus, is to insert your *own* sqlplus script in the path before the Oracle one, along the lines of (not thoroughly tested):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" != "/" ]] ; then
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "$@"
    exit
fi
shift
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus $MY_ORA_USER/$MY_ORA_PWD "$@"
```

This would then be the one called by your script and it would check the first parameter to see if it was the simple `/`. If not, it would call the real `sqlplus` with the same parameters.

Otherwise, it would replace the `/` with a user/password formed from the `MY_ORA_*` environment variables.